# How can I use Unity 2d with another window manager besides Metacity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, unity-2d

How can I use Unity 2d with another window manager besides Metacity? (like openbox forexample)

Comment: By the way, has anyone filed bugs on metacity and compiz issues, regarding crashing and X unpredictably freezing? I know there are various flickering issues reported, one of at least is cronic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `compiz --replace` to your startup applications. Restart your session (Log out, and then back in again) and you'll now be using Compiz.

A similar action will be used for openbox. I think it's `openbox --replace`

Answer (score 5):

To make changes permamnent, You'll have to edit unity session file.
Here's short guide for Unity2d and openbox:
http://spacecat3000.blogspot.com/2011/11/replace-metacity-with-openbox-in.html

> Install openbox:
>
> 1. `sudo apt-get install openbox`
> 2. Optionally install additional packages (in my case these were installed as dependencies): `sudo apt-get install obconf
>      openbox-themes`
> 3. Edit `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/2d-ubuntu.session` file and replace:
>
>    ```
>    DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity with
>
>    DefaultProvider-windowmanager=openbox
>    ```
> 4. Logout, login (with Unity 2d session).
> 5. Run obconf, choose some nice theme (my was found on box-look.org and changed a little) and configure buttons position.