# Unity launcher menu "reaction speed"

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

Hello all,

I have noticed that, having the Unity on Ubuntu 11.04 in its default configuration, when I move the mouse to the left border of my desktop, the Unity launcher appears "fairly slow" (i.e: it takes 0.5 sec to show up). On the other hand, if I move the mouse to the top left corner of my screen, the Unity launcher shows up instantly.

Is there any way to change the "reaction speed" of the launcher? It bother me a bit this aprox. half a second that it takes to show up.

Am I the only one complaining about this? I couldn't find any information about this "issue" so far.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not an isuue, thats by design...

Comment: Do you want to increase or decrease the speed? The delay is intentional to avoid accidentally invoking the launcher when you want to interact with something on the left.

Comment: I want to increase the speed. I understand that some delay might be necessary to avoid non desired invocations, as you said, but to me is too slow. Is there any way to parametrize such speed?

Comment: That why I said "issue" and not issue :)

It would be nice to, at least, give the possibility to parametrize such speed.

Comment: I concur with Dan, it seems a little totalitarian to impose such rigidity on the user interface, why the reluctance to give users more control?

Answer (score 2):

The Unity delay is intentional ([Ayatana-Design bug 754583](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/754583)) but can be changed.

*First*
You can change the edge delay of Compiz:
"General Options" → "General" → "Edge Trigger Delay" set to 0

---

*Second*
You can change this delay and others settings. See [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

At the end of the answer by [Octavian Damiean](https://askubuntu.com/users/2732/octavian-damiean) you will find this:

"**Launcher & Menus (unity-preferences)**

There is another option to configure how to show the launcher then it is hidden.

1. Open the `Launcher & Menus` configuration utility by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `unity-preferences`.

   [image: unity-preferences]

   - *Pushes the left edge of the screen* will make the launcher appear about one second after pushing the cursor to the left edge of the screen.
   - *Touches the top left corner of the screen* will make the launcher appear immediately when the cursor touches the top left corner of the screen.
2. Select the desired option."