# How do adjust the launcher slide out time to be instant?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

Hello friends,

i was wondering if anyone knows whether or not it is possible to instantly auto-hide the unity bar, rather then just having it slowly slide out.

Thanks for the eventual answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw this [Unity launcher menu "reaction speed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38406/unity-launcher-menu-reaction-speed)

1st part of the 1st answer is probabaly what you want too:

> The Unity delay is intentional (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/754583)     but can be changed.
>
> You can change the edge delay of Compiz:
>       "General Options" → "General" → "Edge Trigger Delay" set to 0

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what i was looking for. I will give it a go when I'm back at ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

- Install **CompizConfig Settings
  Manager**.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or **Preferences >
  CompizConfig Settings Manager** in
  **Ubuntu Classic**.
- Navigate to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**.

[image]

- Click on the **Experimental tab**.

[image]

- Adjust the **Hide Animation** to your
  liking.

[image]

By design, there is a delay when the launcher slides out. You can always work-around this, by moving the cursor into the **top-left corner** of the screen instead.

Comment: What are you using for window specific screenshots if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Shutter, it is a fantastic program. Give it a try, you will really like the way it does most of everything for you. Select a window, menu, area on the screen, dialog, or notification bubble, and it will do the rest for you. Also has a built-in editor.

Comment: Rinzwind posted just before I submitted mine, and with a similar answer. I will delete my answer in a few minutes, and edit Rinzwind's.

Comment: Thanks for the "guide". Unfortunately it's not what i'm looking for. I guess i will stick with autohide off until instant autohide is avalible

Comment: @Alan, I don't think you should delete your answer, if I may say.  It is easier to follow.

Comment: yours is better! I yield and deleted mine! and thanks for reminding me about 'shutter' . I forgot about that :-D

Comment: I'm sorry Tomas, I will look into it some more, and see if there is a way to adjust it to your liking.

Comment: Tomas, I don't use Unity often as I don't like it, but try moving the mouse to the top-left corner of the screen instead of nudging the left-side. For me, this shows the launcher instantly. This is apparently by design.