# Is it possible to change the unity launcher delay to absolute zero?

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

although I have seen similar questions and the hint to change it in ccsm under general options, I find it still taking way to long. I have set the Edge Trigger Delay value to zero and still I have to wait over a second to make the launcher pop up. I can't believe that this really can't be speeded up so I am asking here. I don't want go back to using docky instead just of that little thing.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but it will appear instantly if you move your mouse to the top left corner.

Comment: I've changed the answer trying to suite your need ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for "absolute zero" delay

**1)** We will need [XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install these from the *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here (xdotool)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [here (Compiz)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

**2)** Open Compiz (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**3)** Go to Commands and add `xdotool key super` to one command

[image: img]

**4)** Then go to Edge Bindings and choose Left.

[image: img]