# Any ways to make Unity pop up faster/better?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

The Unity bar on the left side of the screen doesn't pop up correctly when moving the pointer to the left side of the screen.

It frequently doesn't pop up, especially when it's been popped up few seconds ago. In those cases, I have to move the pointer to the center of the screen, and go back to the left side again. Of course, I can hold the Super-key, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I'm also looking for ways to make the bar pop up faster in general: it would be great if the speed could be user-defined, just like the alt-tab-window-switching speed can be modified in CompizConfig. Right now, in my opinion, it pops up too slowly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Exeleration-G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your cursor to the very top left hand of the screen and you will see that the launcher appears slightly faster than moving the cursor to the left of the screen to make the launcher appear.

I have just done exactly what I have detailed and have noticed better launcher appearance times than previously just moving it towards the left of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also thanks for reporting the duplicate. I've done some searching on the internet and on aksubuntu.com, but the term 'delay' didn't pop up in my head as a searching term. Thanks