# How to change unity launcher auto-*hide* delay?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

Is there anyway to change the delay before the launcher hides?  I know it's possible to make the launcher appear quickly, but I can't figure out anyway to make it disappear without the 1-second delay.