# Mutter: Global menu integration

Tags: unity-2d, panel, window-manager, appmenu, mutter

Is it possible to have Mutter merge the title bar of maximized windows and the panel, like happens with Compiz and Metacity? I want to try to replace Metacity with Mutter in Unity 2D, and so far it looks good appart from the missing panel integration.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found something!

1. `sudo apt-get install maximus`
2. ALT+F2
3. `maximus`
4. ALT+F2
5. `gconf-editor`
6. Set `/apps/maximus/no_maximize` to *true*
7. Add `maximus` to the startup applications.