# How to reenable "Aero Snap"  in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-2d

I want to get back "Aero Snap", the behavior when dragging windows to the upper Ubuntu bar, they maximized automatically. I must have done something to the behavior of that thing because now I can't do that any more, I have to double click the window or press the maximize button.

Comment: I noticed that you tagged this [tag:unity-2d]. Unity 2D never had this feature by default. Were you using something else before the upgrade? You might also want to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/41566/how-do-i-get-aero-snap-in-unity-2d

Comment: OP never responded to comment posted 5+ years ago. OP hasn't signed on in 2+ years. This question is about EOL version and has no answers. VTC as `not reproducible`