# How can I configure the launcher in Unity 2D?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)

Is it possible to resize the Unity 2D launcher?

Is it possible to change the reveal mode from the left edge with delay to the top left corner without delay?

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal to merge that will allow resizing of the unity-2d launcher, Atm still 'needs review' due to some concerns.

Hopefully it will get squared away, merged & released. As it is now would be done thru dconf-editor or gsettings. (though if not, it or some variation of, could end up in a ppa at some point

I've found it works well & because I would be using it none of the concerns  matter here. It's caused no issue in use

https://code.launchpad.net/~thiago-nsantos/unity-2d/launcher-width/+merge/79974

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe your question is the same:

[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903)

look there is the answer :-)

Comment: No, this is Unity 3D. My questions asks for Unity 2D

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/video-how-to-change-the-size-of-the-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: This is Unity 3D only.

Answer (score -1):

You can try D-conf tools :
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/dconf-tools

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.