# Change Icon Size in Unity 2D Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Unity 2D launcher icons smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-launcher-icons-smaller)

Is it possible to change the icon sizes of the buttons in the launcher used in Unity 2D?

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, here is no way to change the launcher width in Unity 2D, as you can read here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/158873

https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/141757

I suggest to register to this bug on launchpad, that is the related feature request:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/789638

Note: the are few other options you can choose, see question [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)

Answer (score 0):

You might actually not need to be using Unity 2D.  I found that if I tried to log in to just ubuntu I would get just the background but no Unity 3D; 2D log in worked fine. However if after downloading Gnome-shell I could log into "Classic no effects" then in a terminal window type "Unity" and I can get the Unity 3D shell working that way and be able to change icon size etc from compiz.  I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this but the workaround worked for me.