# Unable to change the launcher icon size

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the size of Unity 2D launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-unity-2d-launcher-icons)

After upgrading to 11.10 I can't change the launcher icon size to smaller.

I've tried to change it using `ccsm`, like described in [How can I configure Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903), but the changes take no effects (restarted, tried `sudo` - still big icons). In the previous version of Ubuntu this solution worked.

How can I change the icon size?

(BTW, how can I know which Unity (2D vd 3D) I'm running and switch between?).

#### Edit:

Looks like I'm using Unity 2D and have some problems with graphics:

```
me@my-laptop ~ $ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: unable to create the OpenGL context
```

#### Edit 2

```
me@my-laptop ~ $ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
```

Comment: @fossfreedom So how to change the icon size in 2D or go back to 3D?

Comment: this will tell you what version you are running (http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d) - and you should monitor this question for "how to change icon size in unity 2d" http://askubuntu.com/questions/66543/change-icon-size-in-unity-2d-launcher.  As to how to go back to 3D - have you run the support test? http://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks, see my edit for more details. In the previous Ubuntu I used Unity without any problems. See my other latest questions for problems that appeared after the upgrade.

Comment: can you add your graphics card (lspci | grep VGA) together with what driver (if any) you are using from the Additional Drivers window

Comment: @fossfreedom See the edit.

Comment: oh dear - I'll leave others to answer this one - you've got optimus graphics.  Suggest do a quick search - there are lots of similar questions!

Comment: @fossfreedom Looks like I need https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee

Comment: @fossfreedom Installing Bimblebee fixed the issues with the graphics card, now I'm running Unity 3D where I can change the icon size. Post any answer, I'll accept is as your comments were very helpful. Thanks.