# How can I change the size of Unity 2D launcher icons?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d

Is it possible to make Unity 2D launcher icons smaller or larger than the default size?

Comment: There is a way to reduce the size of icons in the launcher described here: [Changing icon size in Unity 2d Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11777886&postcount=1). It involves editing .qml files and the editing may have to be redone each time Unity 2D is updated. Very painful, in my opinion.

Comment: Worked fine and painlessly: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-unity-2d-resize-launcher.html

Answer (score 8):

## 11.10

There  is a way to make the icons smaller, however the icons are surrounded by backlit that's always 54x54 px and you can't shrink that, it's hard coded.
What you can do is this:[image]

Comment: The dynamic width Launcher for Unity2d has seen some attention, but probably won't make it into Precise. https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/175008 (#24)

Answer (score 5):

### 12.04

**Update**:

There is a little script to change the size of the Unity-2d launcher items. Download the script from [the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1954637) (you need to login to download the file).

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Use the script to change the size of the Unity-2D launcher item:

```
sudo script.py 32
```

Here, I have used 32 as an example. You can use other icon sizes as you wish.

References:

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-adjust-size-of-unity-2d-launcher-and-icons/
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-change-unity-2d-launcher-icon-size-with-a-script/

---

**Original answer**:

As of writing this answer, it is not possible to change the size of the launcher icons easily. [Georgi's hackish method](https://askubuntu.com/a/105317/25798) is the best possible way to change the icon size.

The feature to change the icon size is still not fully developed yet and hopefully, it will land in for 12.04.

See https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/175008.

Comment: This worked for me - though I had to do `sudo /script.py 32` (and log out and in to see it).

Comment: ...even though I had done the chmod+x  It also got reset after an update so may be doing this a few times.

Comment: Each update would overwrite the file you edited. So, you need to modify the icons each time.

Comment: @souravc The link is OK, all you have to to is login, to download.  Or just click [here](https://copy.com/w2nQthA1vxduivis), to download.

Answer (score 5):

The slider for resize icons - Launcher is not available in ubuntu-2d (Unity 2D) session. 
So I assume you are using Unity 2D.

An ascertainment of which session you use , would be

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

command in terminal.

**If you want to resize the Launcher - Icons in Ubuntu-2d (Unity 2D) session** you must "hack" some items manually.

Carefully read and carefully apply bellow changes.

Open the terminal and do

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/Shell.qml
```

find this entry

```
LauncherLoader {
    id: launcherLoader
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    width: 65
```

and change the width to 52.

Save - close  and then again

```
 gksudo gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/common/IconTile.qml
```

find the entry

```
 Image {
    id: icon
    objectName: "icon"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    smooth: true

    sourceSize.width: 48
    sourceSize.height: 48
```

and change the sourcesSize.width and sourceSize.height to 32

save - close the file and then again

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/LauncherList.qml
```

find the section

```
AutoScrollingListView {
id: list
Accessible.name: objectName

/* The spacing is explicitly set in order to compensate
   the space added by selectionOutline and round_corner_54x54.png. */
spacing: -7

property int tileSize: 54

/* selectionOutline tile size, so AutoScrollingList view can calculate
   the right height. */
property int selectionOutlineSize:  65
```

and change the titeSize to 40 and selectionOutlineSize to 52.

Save the file and logout - login for changes take effect.

Enjoy and be aware that with an update in the future maybe (not for sure) these values returned to defaults.

**This procedure was previously described here in March 2012**: [Changing icon size in Unity 2d Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11777886&postcount=1).

Answer (score 4):

You can change icon size in 12.04.  Go to the forums and see my post on this in the Desktop Environments forum

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1943423