# No launcher icon size option in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, launcher, icons, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Unity 2D launcher icons smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-launcher-icons-smaller)

This is really weird but I really don't have the option to resize my launcher icons in the System Settings -> Appearance Menu as I should...

Actually I enter Unity (3D) but the launcher panel seems like the one from Unity 2D...

Comment: I strongly suspect you are running unity-2d not 3D - you can check this by this Q&A.  Flag this if this is incorrect and I'll reopen. http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: that is probably a graphics issue.  Create a new question but with details of your graphics card.  thanks.

Comment: I cannot press the flag button for some reason...

Comment: You were right. It had to do with my graphics driver. I have this issue since 11.10 .