# Missing ability to change the size of launcher icons

Tags: launcher, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Unity 2D launcher icons smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-launcher-icons-smaller)

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04, well upgraded would be the correct thing to say. I also downloaded and created a disc of it, which I looked at on my win7 laptop while this desktop was still upgrading (close to 5 hours to do so!)  Anyway, I noticed while using my disk as live cd that you could change the size of the launcher icons. Now that it is installed on this computer, I don't have that option... I can only change whether the launcher auto-hides or not.

Having a problem with xscreensaver as well, but directed that to xscreensaver.

Could this just be that the upgrade didn't go well? Should I just do a clean install from the disk (not out of the question, I'm new to Linux)?

Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The option to change the size of the Launcher icons is only available in Unity, while you seem to be running Unity2d. Log out, click the cog wheel icon (might be a circle now), and select Ubuntu as session, and log back in.

It's also possible to reduce the icons size in Unity2d, but the procedure is a bit advanced.
[How can I change the size of Unity 2D launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-launcher-icons-smaller)

Comment: Well, I hope you get this response, as I can't seem to figure out how to respond directly.    I did as you advised, logged out, and when I went to log back on, I had 2 options...Ubuntu or Ubuntu2D. Neither is giving me the option to resize the launcher icons (as the CD does). Could something have gone whacky in the download/upgrade?   Anne

Comment: It's possible. If you want to troubleshoot, we'll need to see the output of `lspci | grep VGA` from a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t).

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: Thanks. That is an old (2003 according to Wikipedia) Intel's graphical accelerator, I really don't think it can run Unity, which require 3d and decent hardware acceleration. It will only do Unity2d or Gnome Classic. Sorry. Check out Unity's hardware requirements: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements

Comment: Ok... when you wanted to know about the graphics, my brain started thinking about little stuff that I noticed, and it kinda fell into place (little nuances suddenly made sense).  :)  Thanks for your help.    Per chance...do you know anything about said graphic card being upgraded? I know it's built in to the motherboard, so does that mean I have to buy a card and find a place to install it, or is a card something that can be upgraded?

Comment: Hm..., is there an AGP slot on the motherboard? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AGP_slot.jpg On the second thought, I honestly don't think an upgrade would be worthwhile. You'll have to buy another card, ATI, Nvidia 8600 or higher, which would cost more then that computer is worth now, and I am not even sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks!  And thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I do now have the autohide option (did not have in 11.10), so I'll be just fine with that. :)