# Compiz in Precise 12.04 - Unity 2D

Tags: unity, compiz, 12.04, metacity, 2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Unity 2D launcher icons smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-make-unity-2d-launcher-icons-smaller)

I'm looking to be able to tweak some things in Unity 2D. I have an older machine with a Celeron M 2.2GHz and only 2GB RAM, so some things bog it down - like Unity 3D (although I haven't tried it in 12.04. Should I?)

My question is this, can I use Compiz or Metacity or some other solution to change the size of the icons in the launcher, for example?

I'm very happy with the speed of my machine in Unity 2D, but when I tried Unity 3D in 11.10, it ran veeeerrrry slowly.

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to change the icon size in Unity 2D - also not even with third-party software. Sorry. There exists a script to modify the icon size, buts not recommended for further updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sure use this script [script to change icon size in unity-2d](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1954637)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of the launcher in Unity 2D as yet, but you might want to give Unity 3D a try again because it has had various improvements and might work for you where it wasn't working before.

Comment: OK. I'm trying it at this moment. Ubuntu crashed as soon as I logged on, but I allowed it to submit a report through Apport and I assume (?) it rebooted...since I'm here.

Comment: Oops.  But yes, it seems to be working now. My machine seems to be running normally which wasn't the case with Unity 3D in 11.10. Thank you for the suggestion!