# What happened to my launcher icon size slider in Settings>Appearance and how can I get it back?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the size of Unity 2D launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-unity-2d-launcher-icons)

When I first installed 12.04 LTS, only a week ago I had access to at least two cool features:

(1) the orange box that appeared when you drag a window to the top or either side of the screen (let go and the window would fill the box); and

(2) a slider bar in Settings → Appearance that allowed me to change the size of the icons in my launcher.

A week later I installed some updates, and now both of those things are gone.

Anyone else have this problem? How can I fix it?

I may have two separate issues, but it seems to me to be more than coincidence that they became dysfunctional about the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You appear to be "falling back" to Unity 2D, since both those things are features of Unity 3D. Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`