# How to resize Launcher on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the size of Unity 2D launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82395/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-unity-2d-launcher-icons)

Ther is no slider bar for adjusting launcher in System Settings -> Appearance.