# How can I set the Unity2D launcher to be always shown?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)

Is it possible to have the bar on the left side always on top? 
I fixed this for Unity 3D, but I'm now using Unity 2D and when a window is maximized the launcher is hidden.

How can I have always the launcher shown?

Comment: The answer for this is already given by @greg