# Arrange icons on unity 2d bar

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-2d

I can't arrange icons on 2d unity bar. Whenever I'm trying to drag icons whole bar dragged up and down instead! I can only remove and add app icons to bar, but they always added at end, just before workspaces icon.

Is there any nice way to reorganize icons except wiping all icons from unity bar and re-adding them in desired order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to add -

In unity-2d you can move icons up or down directly in the launcher - just l.click on & hold the click for about a sec. The icon will move slightly & then can be re-positioned

In unity-2d you can only move up or down inside the launcher unlike unity-3d where you can pull the icon out of the launcher

Answer (score 2):

You need to click on the icon and keep the left mouse button down. After a few miliseconds, the two side arrows will disappear, then you can move the icon up/down.

Comment: brilliant!  how did you know that?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use the `dconf-editor`. First install [dconf-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools], then navigate to **desktop>unity>launcher**, and edit the list of favourites so that it is arranged as you like.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

If you click the icon, drag it outside the bar (to the right) and then place it where you would like it will work. You just can't click and drag within the bar, otherwise you end up with the results you described where the logos just scroll themselves up and down the bar