# Everything but launcher and menu bar is black

Tags: configuration

I tried to make my launcher a different color in Unity-2D (using dconf-editor and directly changing files as per [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)). Now I can't see my background or any programs, and all I see is a black screen, the top menu bar, and the launcher. Programs boot, but I can't see them; the launcher responds correctly, so I know they're there, I simply can't see anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's *extremely odd*. Can you please try lgging from different account (Guest would do it too) to unity-2d and see if the issues exist? 
If they do, try reinstalling Unity 2D packages.