# How do you use Openbox with Unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, openbox

I am not a fan of the way that Metacity positions its Close, Maximize and Minimize buttons on the left of the screen. Is there any way to change this? If not, is there any way to use Openbox with Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Unity 2d with another window manager besides Metacity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22055/how-can-i-use-unity-2d-with-another-window-manager-besides-metacity)

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97010/ubuntu-with-gnome-and-openbox . I also suggust Lubuntu (well actually I would use lxqt)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you, you cannot use the Openbox with unity. Unity is an extension of compiz and doesn't use metacity. But if you're okay with losing the launcher and menubar at the top then you could use openbox as its own desktop environment.